# Splitting string on spaces unless in double quotes but double quotes can have a preceding string attached

Tags: java, regex, split

I need to split a string in Java (first remove whitespaces between quotes and then split at whitespaces.)

> "abc test=\"x y z\"   magic=\"  hello   \"   hola"

becomes:

**firstly:**

> "abc test=\"xyz\"   magic=\"hello\"   hola"

**and then:**

- abc
- test="xyz"
- magic="hello"
- hola

Scenario :
I am getting a string something like above from input and I want to break it into parts as above. One way to approach was first remove the spaces between quotes and then split at spaces. Also string before quotes complicates it. Second one was split at spaces but not if inside quote and then remove spaces from individual split. I tried capturing quotes with "\"([^\"]+)\"" but I'm not able to capture just the spaces inside quotes. I tried some more but no luck.

Comment: You essentially want to write a parser. Then output the data in whatever format you want. Regex on it's own may not be the right solution for you. Can you show us what you have tried, as well as what the goal is (why you are doing this)

Comment: You can try `System.out.println("abc   test=\"x y z\"   magic=\"  hello   \"   hola".replace("   ", ",\n"));`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can do this using a formal pattern matcher.  The secret sauce of the answer below is to use the not-much-used `Matcher#appendReplacement` method.  We pause at each match, and then append a custom replacement of anything appearing inside two pairs of quotes.  The custom method `removeSpaces()` strips all whitespace from each quoted term.

```
public static String removeSpaces(String input) {
    return input.replaceAll("\\s+", "");
}

String input = "abc test=\"x y z\" magic=\" hello \" hola";
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\"(.*?)\"");
Matcher m = p.matcher(input);
StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer("");
while (m.find()) {
    m.appendReplacement(sb, "\"" + removeSpaces(m.group(1)) + "\"");
}
m.appendTail(sb);

String[] parts = sb.toString().split("\\s+");
for (String part : parts) {
    System.out.println(part);
}

abc
test="xyz"
magic="hello"
hola
```

### Demo

The big caveat here, as the above comments hinted at, is that we are really using a regex engine as a rudimentary parser.  To see where my solution would fail fast, just remove one of the quotes by accident from a quoted term.  But, if you are sure you input is well formed as you have showed us, this answer might work for you.

Comment: Nice answer!. Never knew about "Pattern".

Answer (score 1):

I wanted to mention the java 9's [**`Matcher.replaceAll`**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#replaceAll-java.util.function.Function-) lambda extension:

```
// Find quoted strings and remove there whitespace:
s = Pattern.compile("\"[^\"]*\"").matcher(s)
    .replaceAll(mr -> mr.group().replaceAll("\\s", ""));

// Turn the remaining whitespace in a comma and brace all.
s = '{' + s.trim().replaceAll("\\s+", ", ") + '}';
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably the other answer is better but still I have written it so I will post it here ;) It takes a different approach

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        String test="abc test=\"x y z\"   magic=\"  hello   \"   hola";
          Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("([^\\\"]+=\\\"[^\\\"]+\\\" )");
            Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(test);
            int lastIndex=0;
            while(matcher.find()) {
                String[] parts=matcher.group(0).trim().split("=");

                boolean newLine=false;
                for (String string : parts[0].split("\\s+")) {
                    if(newLine)
                        System.out.println();
                    newLine=true;
                    System.out.print(string);
                }
                System.out.println("="+parts[1].replaceAll("\\s",""));
                lastIndex=matcher.end();
            }
            System.out.println(test.substring(lastIndex).trim());           
    }
```

Result is

```
abc
test="xyz"
magic="hello"
hola
```

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want to write a basic parser/Tokenizer. My bet is that after you make something that can deal with pretty printing in this structure, you will soon want to start validating that there arn't any mis-matching `"`'s.

But in essence, you have a few stages for this particular problem, and Java has a built in tokenizer that can prove useful.

```
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.StringTokenizer;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class Q50151376{

    private static class Whitespace{
        Whitespace(){ }
        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "\n";
        }
    }

    private static class QuotedString {
        public final String string;

        QuotedString(String string) {
            this.string = "\"" + string.trim() + "\"";
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return string;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String test = "abc test=\"x y z\" magic=\" hello \" hola";
        StringTokenizer tokenizer = new StringTokenizer(test, "\"");
        boolean inQuotes = false;
        List<Object> out = new LinkedList<>();
        while (tokenizer.hasMoreTokens()) {
            final String token = tokenizer.nextToken();
            if (inQuotes) {
                out.add(new QuotedString(token));
            } else {
                out.addAll(TokenizeWhitespace(token));
            }
            inQuotes = !inQuotes;
        }

        System.out.println(joinAsStrings(out));
    }

    private static String joinAsStrings(List<Object> out) {
        return out.stream()
                .map(Object::toString)
                .collect(Collectors.joining());
    }

    public static List<Object> TokenizeWhitespace(String in){
        List<Object> out = new LinkedList<>();
        StringTokenizer tokenizer = new StringTokenizer(in, " ", true);

        boolean ignoreWhitespace = false;
        while (tokenizer.hasMoreTokens()){
            String token = tokenizer.nextToken();
            boolean whitespace = token.equals(" ");
            if(!whitespace){
                out.add(token);
                ignoreWhitespace = false;
            } else if(!ignoreWhitespace) {
                out.add(new Whitespace());
                ignoreWhitespace = true;
            }
        }
        return out;
    }

}
```